# How can I dynamically set "start_urls" with CrawlSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using CrawlSpider with rule linkextractor. I would like to dynamically set start_urls referring to external file with the following code, but it didn't work.

Followings are the error message and my codes.
This may be a simple/stupid question, but I really appreciate it if someone would give me a hint to solve my problem. Thank you in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 88, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

```
class StorelistSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawler"

    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        #Target Category
        with open('CategoryList.txt') as f1:
            for q1 in f1:
                targetCategory = q1

                #Target Prefecture
                with open('prefectureList.txt') as f2:
                    for q2 in f2:
                        prefectureName = q2


                        start_urls=("https://example.com/" + q2 + "/")

                        #rules to follow links:
                        rules = (
                            #follow area link first, then category link next, check list pages and go to the details
                            Rule(LinkExtractor(
                                allow=r"/\w+/A\d{4}/$",
                                restrict_xpaths = "//*[@id='js-leftnavi-area-scroll']",
                                unique = True,)),
                            Rule(LinkExtractor(
                                allow=r"/\w+/A\d{4}/rstLst/" + "{}".format(targetCategory) + r"/$",
                                restrict_xpaths = "//*[@id='js-leftnavi-genre-balloon']",
                                unique = True,)),
                            Rule(LinkExtractor(
                                allow=r"/\w+/A\d{4}/rstLst/" + "{}".format(targetCategory) + r"/\d*/$",
                                restrict_xpaths = "//*[@id='container']/div[15]/div[4]/div/div[7]/div/ul",
                                unique = True,)),
                            Rule(LinkExtractor(
                                allow=r"/\w+/A\d{4}/A\d{6}/\d+/$",
                                restrict_xpaths = "//*[@id='container']/div[15]/div[4]/div/div[6]",
                                unique = True,
                            ), callback="page_parse"),
                        )

    def page_parse(self, response):
        yield Page.from_response(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `start_requests` method must return a iterator. Please see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

Also, `rules` must be declared as class attribute. Please see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example

So, your example should look like:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class StorelistSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawler"

    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    #rules to follow links:
    rules = (
        #follow area link first, then category link next, check list pages and go to the details
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=r"/\w+/A\d{4}/$",
            restrict_xpaths = "//*[@id='js-leftnavi-area-scroll']",
            unique = True,)),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=r"/\w+/A\d{4}/rstLst/" + "{}".format(targetCategory) + r"/$",
            restrict_xpaths = "//*[@id='js-leftnavi-genre-balloon']",
            unique = True,)),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=r"/\w+/A\d{4}/rstLst/" + "{}".format(targetCategory) + r"/\d*/$",
            restrict_xpaths = "//*[@id='container']/div[15]/div[4]/div/div[7]/div/ul",
            unique = True,)),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            allow=r"/\w+/A\d{4}/A\d{6}/\d+/$",
            restrict_xpaths = "//*[@id='container']/div[15]/div[4]/div/div[6]",
            unique = True,
        ), callback="page_parse"),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        #Target Category
        with open('CategoryList.txt') as f1:
            for q1 in f1:
                targetCategory = q1

                #Target Prefecture
                with open('prefectureList.txt') as f2:
                    for q2 in f2:
                        prefectureName = q2
                        url = "https://example.com/" + q2 + "/"
                        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)


    def page_parse(self, response):
        yield Page.from_response(response)
```

I haven't tested, but this should work (EDIT: would also need to update the rules to remove the `targetCategory` variable. You can write these rules statically or build it on the `__init__` method.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I removed the 'targetCategory' variable and tested.

It worked as follows:
1) 'start_requests' dynamically generate urls,
2) scrapy try to parse those urls. 

However, I want
1) 'start_requests' to dynamically generate urls,
2) scrapy to follow links with rules and LinkExtractors
3) then parse those urls.

There still are something wrong with my code...